# Python - curve_fitting doesn't work properly with high x-values

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I have four XY-points for which I need to obtain a curve, hence I use `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`. Looking at the points, I want to use an exponential function. This works for the lower x-values, but not for the higher x-values.

The code is the following (you can switch between `low_x_values` and `high_x_values`):

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

low_x_values = [3.139, 2.53, 0.821, 0.27]
high_x_values = [859.8791936328762, 805.5080517453312, 639.2578427310567, 496.3622821767497]

list_x = high_x_values
list_y = [0.21, 0.49, 1.56, 23.97]
    
def func_exp(x, a, b, c):
    return a + (b * np.exp(-c * x))

list_line_info, pcov = curve_fit(func_exp, list_x, list_y, maxfev=100000)

plot_x = np.linspace(min(list_x), max(list_x), 1000)
plot_y = list_line_info[0] + ((list_line_info[1]) * np.exp((-list_line_info[2] * plot_x)))

plt.plot(plot_x, plot_y, linestyle='-', color='orangered')
plt.plot(list_x, list_y, linestyle='--', color='dodgerblue')
plt.scatter(list_x, list_y, color='black', zorder=2)
plt.grid()
```

When I want to find the curve for the low values, it shows this:
[image]

However, when I want to do the same for the high values, I get this:
[image]

I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:

1. The equation you're trying to fit doesn't have enough freedom to fit the curve. Your x-values show the fit needs to be shifted, but you haven't given it any way to do that. I'd change the fit function to `a + b*np.exp(-c*(x-d))`.
2. You should be giving the `curve_fit` a good initial guess. I came up with one by plotting the points in Desmos and manually shifting the values until they were somewhat close (it doesn't have to be perfect, just close enough).

```py
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

low = False
low_x_values = [3.139, 2.53, 0.821, 0.27]
high_x_values = [859.8791936328762, 805.5080517453312,
                 639.2578427310567, 496.3622821767497]

list_x = low_x_values if low else high_x_values
list_y = [0.21, 0.49, 1.56, 23.97]


def func_exp(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a + b*np.exp(-c*(x-d))

p0 = (0.3,100,5,0) if low else (0, 900, 0.008, 10)
list_line_info, pcov = curve_fit(func_exp, list_x, list_y, p0=p0)

plot_x = np.linspace(min(list_x), max(list_x), 1000)
plot_y = func_exp(plot_x, *list_line_info)

plt.plot(plot_x, plot_y, linestyle="-", color="orangered")
plt.plot(list_x, list_y, linestyle="--", color="dodgerblue")
plt.scatter(list_x, list_y, color="black", zorder=2)
plt.grid()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I updated the code to test it like I need it to be, but I face another issue with other y-values. I have set p0 = (0, max(list_x), 0, max(list_y)), which works for all lists but one: list_x = [859.8791936328762, 805.5080517453312, 639.2578427310567, 496.3622821767497],  list_y = [0.01, 0.01, 0.04, 2.46]. Do you know what I can do here?