# Python - curve_fitting automating initial guesses

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I asked the following question yesterday and this is an extension of this question:
[Python - curve_fitting doesn't work properly with high x-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77099062/python-curve-fitting-doesnt-work-properly-with-high-x-values/77099276#77099276)

For completeness, I will explain the situation again.
I have four XY-points for which I need to obtain a curve, hence I use `scipy.optimize.curve_fit`. Looking at the points, I want to use an exponential function. I had some issues with this, but someone was able to fix it and with that I have the code example below:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

## X
# list_x1: [3.139, 2.53, 0.821, 0.27]
# list_x2: [859.8791936328762, 805.5080517453312, 639.2578427310567, 496.3622821767497]

## Y
# list_y1: [0.21, 0.49, 1.56, 23.97]
# list_y2: [0.01, 0.01, 0.04, 2.46]

list_x = [859.8791936328762, 805.5080517453312, 639.2578427310567, 496.3622821767497]
list_y = [0.01, 0.01, 0.04, 2.46]


def func_exp(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a + b*np.exp(-c*(x-d))

p0 = (0, max(list_x), 0, max(list_y))
list_line_info, pcov = curve_fit(func_exp, list_x, list_y, maxfev=100000, p0=p0)

plot_x = np.linspace(min(list_x), max(list_x), 1000)
plot_y = func_exp(plot_x, *list_line_info)

plt.plot(plot_x, plot_y, linestyle="-", color="orangered")
plt.plot(list_x, list_y, linestyle="--", color="dodgerblue")
plt.scatter(list_x, list_y, color="black", zorder=2)
plt.grid()
```

The code worksin my program for all lists I enter, except for one combination. The problem is with initial guess values. The suggestion that was made in the other question to use these and this worked. Then I tried to automate this by using `p0 = (0, max(list_x), 0, max(list_y))`. This works for all graphs (all combinations of `list_x1`, `list_x2` and `list_y1`), but not for the combination `list_x2` and `list_y2`.

Combination `list_x1` and `list_y2`:

[image]

Combination `list_x2` and `list_y2` :
[image]

The initial guess `p0 = (0, max(list_x), 0.01, max(list_y))` does work in the combination `list_x2` and `list_y2`, but then I have the same issue with the combination `list_x1` and `list_y2`

Am I missing something here?

EDIT

I updated the code according to the suggestions made in the comments:

```
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

## X
# list_x1: [3.139, 2.53, 0.821, 0.27]
# list_x2: [859.8791936328762, 805.5080517453312, 639.2578427310567, 496.3622821767497]

## Y
# list_y1: [0.21, 0.49, 1.56, 23.97]
# list_y2: [0.01, 0.01, 0.04, 2.46]

list_x = [859.8791936328762, 805.5080517453312, 639.2578427310567, 496.3622821767497]
list_y = [0.21, 0.49, 1.56, 23.97]


def func_exp(x, a, b, c, d):
    return a + b*np.exp(-c*(x-d))

p0 = (0, max(list_y), 0, max(list_x))
list_line_info, pcov = curve_fit(func_exp, list_x, list_y, maxfev=100000, p0=p0)

plot_x = np.linspace(min(list_x), max(list_x), 1000)
plot_y = func_exp(plot_x, *list_line_info)

plt.plot(plot_x, plot_y, linestyle="-", color="orangered")
plt.plot(list_x, list_y, linestyle="--", color="dodgerblue")
plt.scatter(list_x, list_y, color="black", zorder=2)
plt.grid()
```

This suggestion does not work for one of the combination used here:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Preliminary note :

You try to fit the function `y = a + b*exp(-c*(x-d))` which the same as `y = a + b*exp(c*d)*exp(-c*x)` which again is the same as `y = a + B*exp(-c*x)` where `B=b*exp(c*d)`

This shows that they are not four independent parameters `a, b, c, d` but only three independent parameters `a, B, c`

Trying to fit a function with non independant parameters leads to not unique solution. Especially with non linear regression the iterative process might be not convergent and/or the result after apprently convergence might be somehow arbitrary.

In the code it is recommended to change `return a + b*np.exp(-c*(x-d))` into `return a + b*np.exp(-c*x)`.

ANSWER TO THE QUESTION :

The method of nonlinear regression that you use involves iterative calculus and requires "guessed" initial values of parameters. To expect convergence of the process the initial values have to be sufficiently close to the unknown correct values. This is the difficulty especially if one want an automatic process.

In order to overcome the difficulty a way (when possible) is to use a non-iterative method of regression which doesn't requires initial values. Such amethod is explained in https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14674814/Regressions-et-equations-integrales

The application to the case of exponential function is shown below. Since no iterative calculus is used the algoritm is very simple and can be coded in any math software.

Be careful with parameter c. In the calculus below the function is `y = a + b*exp(c*x)` instead of `y = a + *exp(-c*x)` in your question. So the result below is negative c and has to be change to positive to agree to your function.

[image]

Numerical example with your data (x,y) computed with Mathcad software :

[image]

OTHER EXAMPLES :

[image]

[image]

[image]

COMMENT :

The non iterative method is based on the fitting of a linear integral equation to which the considered function is a solution. Thus the accuracy of the result is dependant on the accuracy of the numerical integration (calculus of Sk). If the number of points is low the numerical integration is poor. This is the present case. I am surprised that the calculus continue to work with only four points.

In other words with only four points one cannot expect a good fit. Thus the above results must not be taken as final results. One should improve the results in using again non-linear regression (such as with your software). The above approximate values of the parameters can be used as good initial values for your sofware.

This is a way to automate initial guesses.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is good, but you are missing something, the equation you are trying to fit is:

[image: y(x)= a+b\exp{-\frac{c}{x-d}}]

This is similar to an exponential decay (related to the inverse of x). If we follow your fist assumption, neglecting a and d, as initial value, we get:

[image: y(x)=b\exp{-\frac{c}{x}}]

Here we can see that b is similar to the amplitude. This way, in a case that c was equal x_0 (500 in this case) then b=e*y_0 would fit perfectly the first point. Hence, we can see that b and c relate to y and x respectively.

In your case, you make your initial estimation with p0 = (0, max(list_x), 0, max(list_y)). Hence, relating b to x and d to y, which for values of the same order of magnitude do not make much difference. You iterate around 100,000 times. However, when x and y are not the same order of magnitude, the warranty of fitting nicely the points is really low. If we look at the case your function does not manage to fit the result, you start with very height b and really low c compared to y and x. This way the first estimation of y will be too big, same order as x.

For this reason, an approach where your initial values are p0 = (0, max(list_y), 0, max(list_x)) would make more sense. The values would still be a bit off, but it is just a matter of a few iterations to get to the best fitting values.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I used your suggestion by using p0 = (0, max(list_y), 0, max(list_x)), this does not work for the combination list_x2 and list_y1. I also used all zeros, but I check the deviations (in percentage) between two lines these deviate now around 20% (before it was less than 10% for the lines that worked).

Comment: It would be helpful if you would explain me how are you calculating the deviation, as I cannot find such error. My fittings seem to fit quite well and consistently the combination list_x2 and list_y1, like way better than if I do p0 = (0, max(list_x), 0, max(list_y)). Something might be off somewhere.

Comment: I might be better to discuss the first comment first: your suggestion for p0 does not work here for the combination list_x2 and list_y1. Does it work well for you?

Comment: Yes, when trying p0 = (0, max(list_y), 0, max(list_x)), I get to fit the points quite nicely, for any of the combinations. I cannot confirm deviation, but the graphics look like the job is done.

Comment: I updated the qeustion with your suggestion, but I also added the plot where it doesn't work.

Comment: It is weird your code works perfectly for me. I have no idea of how to help you out here, if it helps I am using Python 3.10 with Scipy version 1.11.2. You might be using an outdated version? I don't know. Hope you ca find the solution you need.